# Converting simple pagination in jquery into javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following Jquery code and I need to convert it into pure javascript code. Can any one please help me to convert it to javascript code.

```js
$('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
  totalPages: 200,
  // the current page that show on start
  startPage: 1,

  // maximum visible pages
  visiblePages: 5,

  initiateStartPageClick: true,

  // template for pagination links
  href: false,

  // variable name in href template for page number
  hrefVariable: '{{number}}',

  // Text labels
  first: 'First',
  prev: 'Previous',
  next: 'Next',
  last: 'Last',

  // carousel-style pagination
  loop: false,

  // callback function
  onPageClick: function(event, page) {
    $('.page-active').removeClass('page-active');
    $('#page' + page).addClass('page-active');
  },

  // pagination Classes
  paginationClass: 'pagination',
  nextClass: 'next',
  prevClass: 'prev',
  lastClass: 'last',
  firstClass: 'first',
  pageClass: 'page',
  activeClass: 'active',
  disabledClass: 'disabled'

});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.page {
  display: none;
}

.page-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-lg pull-right"></ul>
```

and I need to have the same possiblity with javascript , but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far, and where you got stuck..... Which part do you need help with?

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Our role is to help others with their coding attempts, help debug, etc. not to write code for you if you don't know how to :/ You have to make an attempt yourself first, and then, we can help if you're stuck somewhere.

Comment: actually you can't make that because of your plugin is already used JQuery

Comment: @Joseph you mean it's impossible to convert jQuery(and/or jQuery plugins) code to pure JS? :)

Comment: @JeremyThille it is not impossible but it is not a good question because in his case if i understand what he says he needs to rewrite this plugin

Comment: Yes, basically OP needs the same functionality but without jQuery, for some reason. I think it's not going to be easy, because this is a plugin that relies on Bootstrap that relies on jQuery, so basically, the application has to be rewritten from scratch

Comment: The provided jquery code actually contains **very little jquery**.  So there's not much to convert (3 selection and 2 class changes).  The issue is that `twbsPagination()` is a library that relies heavily on jquery, but has not been included as part of the question.  So is OP asking us to rewrite an entire library?  Or just how to do `$("#id")` ?